# Where did "Don't keep activities" go in Android Nougat?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I wanted to test onSafeInstanceState and therefore I usually use the "Don't keep activities" option in the developer settings in Android.
The thing is: It's not there anymore on my Galaxy S7 with Nougat.
Any hints?

Comment: The option still exists on a Nexus 6 running android 7.1.1. Perhaps Samsung removed it from the menu

Comment: I just checked on a Samsung Galaxy S7 edge running Nougat. It's still there.

Comment: Found it! Had my phone set to german. They used a bad translation I guess..